# Why does pandas treat these two strings differently in `apply`?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I wonder why pandas treats the two `lambda`s `l3` and `l4` differently - both take one argument, both return a string, and both should never be executed because `df` is actually empty:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1": [], "col2": []})

l3 = lambda r: ""
l4 = lambda r: f"{r.col1}"

df["col3"] = df.apply(l3, axis=1)
df["col4"] = df.apply(l4, axis=1)  # Error: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1

print(type(df.apply(l3, axis=1)))  # this is a Series
print(type(df.apply(l4, axis=1)))  # this is a DataFrame
```

Yet, the return types of `df.apply` are different.

Bonus question: is there a better way of doing

```py
df["col4"] = df.apply(l4, axis=1)
```

that works for empty data frames?

Update: I believe a relevant part of the pandas code is this:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8e07787bc1030e5d13d3ad5e83b5d060a519ef67/pandas/core/apply.py#L718-L753

In line with what @mozway answered, the function is applied to an empty series, and based on whether this works, returns either the generated new series or a copy of the input (which is a data frame).

In line with what @Brandt commented, one should probably make sure the function works for empty rows, too (which is a weird, at least undocumented requirement).

Comment: Regarding your bonus question: `l4 = lambda r: f"{r.col1}" if len(r) else ""` should do it.

Comment: Also, when I run your code (using the `l4` I suggested above), I get `Series` in both (print/type) cases. I'm using Pandas v1.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud add the `result_type='reduce'` argument to avoid expansion to DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1": [], "col2": []})

l3 = lambda r: ""
l4 = lambda r: f"{r.col1}"

df["col3"] = df.apply(l3, axis=1)
df["col4"] = df.apply(l4, axis=1, result_type='reduce')
```

Comment: Note that `df.apply` *is* working in both cases. What is not working is the assignment to a new column.

Comment: @bers OK, got it, it was an issue of result_type, see edit

Comment: But you were right nonetheless: "When there are no rows, `apply` passes an empty Series to the function.". This just happens in a `try/catch` block so we don't see it failing - see my updated question.